# How to set 'hide' and show on sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, html

I have a template but this js template has error IDK what happens. I want to make this hide and show function sidebar with another js .

```
<div class="mdc-list-group sidebar">// this start sidebar
  <nav class="mdc-list mdc-drawer-menu ">
    <div class="mdc-list-item mdc-drawer-item">
      <a class="mdc-drawer-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dinas">


        <header class="mdc-toolbar mdc-elevation--z4 mdc-toolbar--fixed">
          <div class="mdc-toolbar__row">
            <section class="mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-start">
              <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__menu-icon ">menu</a>//this is for button to click show and hide
              <span class="mdc-toolbar__input">

          </span>
            </section>
```

I add this code in my last script under `</html>`

```
<script>
  function hideSidebar() {
    $(".sidebar").hide();
  }
  hideSidebar();
</script>
```

but its still not work  , whats wrong about this ? thanks you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be executing the Javascript part before the page has loaded, or before the DOM element you are trying to hide has already appeared.

```
 function hideSidebar() {
    $(".sidebar").hide();
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
       hideSidebar();   // only execute this after the page has loaded
 });
```

Comment: you should add it before `</body>` closing tag @AdhikMulat

Comment: ok i its solved but is not solved this problem . can i ask more ?

Comment: @AdhikMulat if you have a different question, please post a new question on the site. If you have queries regarding the same question, please let me know